# UNICODE in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winforms, clr

I am using CLR/CLI windows form application in visual studio and I need to display a 'θ' symbol in textbox. I am using the C++ language. Currently using this code:

```
textBox4->Text += "\r\n" + "\u03F4";
```

The output becomes ?. I've also tried adding a command line utf_8 but still not working.

What can be done to display it??

Comment: Is `\u03F4` UTF-8? Or is it UTF-16? I am asking because sometimes such things happen when we try to use a character from higher UTF set. So, if your code supports till UTF-8 and the character is UTF-16, it will fail to recognize and will show ? like symbols!

Comment: It is a c++ encoding for the unicode symbol. I am having trouble to display the symbols. I am new to this. So any help?

Comment: Try copying the theta symbol and paste it instead of `\u03F4`. Like this: `textBox4->Text += "\r\n" + "θ";`. Check if this works!

Comment: It previously said that Some Unicode characters in this file could not be saved in the current codepage. Do you want to resave this file as Unicode. It has been showing me '?' instead.

Comment: In your project properties, what is the Character Set set to?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you could set `utf-8` in `File-> Advanced Save Options`. You could display `Advanced Save Options` through `Tools-> Customize-> Add Command-> File->  Advanced Save Options`.
[image]

[image]